# WPF chart control exists by default or I have to do an external download?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, charts

I've been going through previous posts here and also some tutorial videos. It seems like the toolbox option has the chart control option since 4.0 and doesn't need any extra downloads.

But in my case, the tool box starts with Pointer, followed by some common WPF controls and then all the WPF controls such as button, canvas and so on. I don't see the chart control.

Read up that I may be missing an assembly reference. The reference seemed to be:

> System.Windows.Control.dataVisualization.toolkit.dll

When I look up the list, I don't even have such a reference available to import. The closest I had was:

> System.Web.DataVisualization

I imported it and it doesn't work too.

Please advice what am I missing. I am looking for chart control to start off and do some simple chart works on my current application. Thank you.

Comment: It's weird. Microsoft released the DataVisualization library with the WPF Toolkit for FW 3.5 under the `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization` namespace, but then included a different version (incompatible) with FW4.0 under the `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization` namespace. Can't find any explanation, comparison, changelist... anything!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for : http://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFToolkit.DataVisualization/

```
<Window x:Class="drawtextonbitmap.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <chartingToolkit:Chart />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you want it to appear in the ToolBox :

- right click ToolBox -> Choose Items
- click Browse
- go to your project folder
- open \packages\WPFToolkit.DataVisualization.3.5.50211.1\lib\System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll
- press Ok
- it will be on 'Common WPF controls' section

Make sure to install mentioned package before using the Package Manager Console : http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console

```
PM> Install-Package WPFToolkit.DataVisualization
```

Comment: I've downloaded the package. I attempt to add it to appear on the toolbox but right clicking ToolBox doesn't have the option choose items.

Comment: You must be editing a XAML file while doing it, not a CS file.

Comment: If nothing worked, then add a Reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx in your project to the DLL mentioned, and paste the code. The 'chartingToolkit' namespace contains the charting classes as you can see it points to the assembly you've mentioned.